# Why is kotlin not working in android studio with the kotlin plugin install

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

[image]
I am new to `Kotlin` and `Android Studio` but at least I follow the instructions in setting it up from JetBrains website but I stuck battling with these errors:

```
Error:(16, 0) Extension with name 'android' does not exist. 
Currently registered extension names: [ext, kotlin]
```

Comment: You need to update to AS 3 canary version

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oficially, Google has announced Kotlin support to Android Studio 3.0 +. Android Studio 3.0 is available in the [Canary channel](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html). Try working with Android Studio 3.0 Canary to get right amount of support and ease for [Kotlin Android](http://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android-tutorial/) language.

Answer (score 2):

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-android

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '<version to use>'

    ...

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

It looks like you are missing the

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: how can you know that if we only see half his gradle file

Comment: Just asume it based on what I see.

Comment: yeah, looks like `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` is missing. @ouchi-princewill can post full gradle file?

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio 2.3.3 not support kotlin sdk 
Download android studio 3.0

---

```
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html
```

Comment: Actually it is possible. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

Comment: Yes .. If you use an earlier version, you'll need to install the Kotlin plugin. Go to File | Settings | Plugins | Install JetBrains plugin… and then search for and install Kotlin.  .. got it